# How to break column with data in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

How can I break column with data like that in google spreadsheet:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

into column with rows like that:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Transpose paste only rotates the data but how can I determine the number of rows?

Comment: it depends a lot on what the REAL pattern is and what (if anything) is in the other columns?

Comment: I am trying to paste data from other side, something like table but I copy only data, and when i paste it into the spreadsheet it look like in my question. There is no empty rows or cells, I would split it after every 5 row

Comment: you're pasting from a website I assume?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A), 3)=0, 
 "♦"&A1:A&"×", "♦"&A1:A),,9^9), "×")), " "), "♦", ))
```

[image]

Comment: i thought i showed you the tidier HLOOKUP() to these!

Comment: Posted. take a gander.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work.

The 3 is the number of columns you'd like to break your data into. the 2 is always 2 regardless!

[image]

Alternative for indefinitely long range:
[image]

Comment: this is new to me, nice one

Comment: but the possible value in A8 & A9 wont show up unless A10 is also filled - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFbux.png

Comment: true, but instead of A2:A7 you can just use A2:A and ROWS(A2:A) instead of COUNTA(A2:A). I added to my post.